# Play / Anorm. Best perfomance

Tags: performance, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

What is best practices to getting best perfomance to executing sql statements in Anorm?

I want to get maximal perfomance from my DB calls.

What is appropriate way to load data from a database and process it (object mapping) as soon as possible?

Should I still use Anorm or I need to use something else, may be "native" jdbc driver?

**UPDATE**
I use **PostgreSQL**.

My database contains **"offices" table**.

In this table exists **4 rows**.

When I run query

```
select
    offices.*
from
    offices
order by
    offices.office__id
```

in PgAdmin then execution time is **1-30 ms**.

So, in Scala code i created **case class Office**:

```
case class Office(
    id,
    name,
    phone,
    address
)
```

Also, I created **OfficeDBO**:

```
case class OfficeDBO(
  id: Long,
  name: String,
  phone: String,
  address: String
)

object OfficeDBO {
  val Mapping = {
    get[Long]("office__id") ~
    get[String]("office__name") ~
    get[String]("office__phone") ~
    get[String]("office__address") map {
      case officeId ~ officeName ~ officePhone ~ officeAddress => OfficeDBO(
        officeId,
        officeName,
        officePhone,
        officeAddress
      )
    }
  }

  def toOffice(officeDBO: OfficeDBO): Office = {
    new Office(
      officeDBO.id,
      officeDBO.name,
      officeDBO.phone,
      officeDBO.address
    )
  }
}
```

And, service method **OfficesService.findOffices()**:

```
def findOffices(): List[Office] = {
    LOGGER.debug("Find offices")

    DB.withConnection(implicit connection => {
      SQL("""
        select
          offices.*
        from
          offices
        order by
          offices.office__id
      """)
      .as(OfficeDBO.Mapping *)
      .map(toOffice)
    })
  }
```

The method **OfficesService.findOffices()** execution at **7 seconds**!

Where is the problem? How to refactor the code that getting maximal perfomance?

Comment: Query optimization will by far have the most impact. Anorm itself is pretty fast, unless you're using ridiculously large prepared statements.

Comment: I added code. Give me advises, please. Whats wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with the code. Though `Office` and `OfficeDBO` are redundant data structures. Is the database local or remote? Is the execution time the same when run multiple times?

Comment: @LimbSoup, I use local PostgreSQL database. Yeap, average time still 4 seconds. How would you write the same code by functionality?

Comment: @LimbSoup the most long operation is calling **"as"** method. **"map"** works momentally.

Comment: It's not really important to the performance, but mapping it the second time doesn't really give you anything new. You're mapping from one case class to another that both have the same structure. Anyway, it's very strange that this is going so slow. There isn't anything wrong with the code, so that leaves the DB driver and connection pool. Are you using anything other than the default configuration?

Comment: @LimbSoup I made greate mistake)) I wrong calculate execution time) Execution time now is really so fast! Big thanks! Cheers!)